# codeigniter .htaccess for controller subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am a beginer in codeigniter and .htaccess. my controller folderis something like

```
/controller
    index.php
    site.php

    /admin
        login.php
```

my problem is, when I access a function sample() which is in "login.php", the url is like

```
"http://localhost/folder1/admin/login/sample"
```

is there any way to hide the "login" part using .htaccess. If some one give me an answer, it will be a great help for me.
Thank you...

Comment: you can use config/routes.php for this

Comment: thank you for the reply. Can you please tell how to do that?

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to change in your .htacees. In your **routes.php**, write this:

```
$route['admin/sample'] = "admin/login/sample";
```

I hope this will help.